# I can't change the text of one button, it changes for all of them in map (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to do a map in React js with button, if i click on a buton, it would change the text of it, but when i click on the button, it changes all the button.

I know the problem is i don't specific the button_id but i don't have any idea to get this.

There is my code:

```
 const assignTutorToChildFunction = (id_child) => {
        setText("Cet enfant est déja ajouté")
    }

    const [text, setText] = useState("Ajouter cet enfant")
    return children.map((element, index) => (
        <StyledTab>
            <Outer style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", color: "yellow" }}>

                <Inner>
                    <th>Prénom</th>
                </Inner>
                <Inner>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                </Inner>
                <Inner>
                    <th>Date de naissance</th>
                </Inner>
                <Inner>
                    <th> Ajout de l'enfant</th>
                </Inner>
                    <Outer>
                        <Inner>

                            <td>{element.firstName} </td>
                        </Inner>
                        <Inner>
                            <td>{element.lastName} </td>
                        </Inner>
                        <Inner>
                            <td>{element.birth}</td>
                        </Inner>
                        <Inner>
                            <button onClick={() => assignTutorToChildFunction(element._id)}>{text} </button>
                        </Inner>
                    </Outer>
                
            </Outer>
        </StyledTab>
    ))

}
```

when i click on a button, all my "Ajouter cet enfant" are replaced by "Cet enfant est deja ajouté")

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work. Essentially, you need to save each text separately, instead of just having one text.

```
const [texts, setTexts] = useState({});

const assignTutorToChildFunction = (id_child) => {
    setText({...texts, [id_child]: "Cet enfant est déja ajouté"});
};

React.useEffect(
    () => {
        let temp_texts = {};
        children.map((element, index) => temp_texts[index] = "Ajouter cet enfant");
        setTexts(temp_texts);
    },
    []
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a state variable. Once you change it, it will cause a re-render and all of your references will be updated.

Better to try to have 2 separate variables containing texts.

```
const tutorUnassignedText = "Ajouter cet enfant";
const tutorAssignedText = "Cet enfant est déja ajouté";
```

then you need a state variable to track where to show which text.

You could try something like this:

```
const [tutorsAssigned, setTutorsAssigned] = useState(Array.from({length: children.length}).fill(false))
```

and then inside your map use:

```
<Inner>
  <button 
onClick={() => setTutorsAssigned(prevState => {
  const tutorsArr = [...prevState];
  tutorsArr[index] = !tutorsArr[index]
  return tutorsArr;
})>
    {tutorsAssigned[index] ? tutorAssignedText : tutorUnassignedText}
  </button>
</Inner>
```

Answer (score 1):

Each child component must have own state:

```
Const ChildComponent = () => {
    const assignTutorToChildFunction = (id_child) => {
      setText("Cet enfant est déja ajouté")
    }
    const [text, setText] = useState("Ajouter cet enfant");
    return (
      <StyledTab>
        <Outer style={{ backgroundColor: "grey", color: "yellow" }}>
            <Inner>
                <th>Prénom</th>
            </Inner>
            <Inner>
                <th>Nom</th>
            </Inner>
            <Inner>
                <th>Date de naissance</th>
            </Inner>
            <Inner>
                <th> Ajout de l'enfant</th>
            </Inner>
                <Outer>
                    <Inner>

                        <td>{element.firstName} </td>
                    </Inner>
                    <Inner>
                        <td>{element.lastName} </td>
                    </Inner>
                    <Inner>
                        <td>{element.birth}</td>
                    </Inner>
                    <Inner>
                        <button onClick={() => assignTutorToChildFunction()}>{text} </button>
                    </Inner>
                </Outer>
            
          </Outer>
      </StyledTab>
  ) ;
} ;

Const ParentComponent = () =>  {
  return children.map((element, index) => (
    <ChildComponent />
  ))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared state, which is used by ALL of your buttons in the loop.

You have 2 options:

1. Extract a brand new component where you'll put the button and where you'll be able to use local state
   or
2. Change state to an array of strings. When you'll be able to manipulate the array depending on the index (or key):

```
const [text, setText] = useState([
  "Ajouter cet enfant",
  "Ajouter cet enfant"
  [...etc]
])
```

Then your callback function will look like that:

```
  const assignTutorToChildFunction = (index) => {
    setText(prevState => {
      const array = [...prevState];
      array[index] = "Ajouter cet enfant"
      return array
    });
  }
```

and the fragment with button:

```
<button
  key={`button-${index}`}
  onClick={() => assignTutorToChildFunction(index)} //You're passing index to you callback function.
>
  {text[index]}{" "}
</button>
```

Edit:
Few things I found in your code:

1. For iterations over children you should use the `Children.map` from React:

```
return Children.map(children, (element, index) => (
```

2. The `assignTutorToChildFunction` functions should use the `useCallback` from React:

```
const assignTutorToChildFunction = useCallback((index) => {
  setText(prevState => {
    const array = [...prevState];
    array[index] = "Ajouter cet enfant"
    return array
  });
})
```